# How to create lookup to event object on custom object

Tags: lookup, event

I want to create a lookup field on custom object(taskray task) to relate it to Event object. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, this is not possible.  Events and Tasks are activities and meant to be children of other objects.

However, you can define the reverse, custom lookup field from Event to another object.

You could do a somewhat wacky workaround with a custom formula field using `HYPERLINK` after some trigger or VF controller figured out what Event the object is a child of and saved the ID of that Event object in your custom object. However, if the Event were deleted, you'd need a trigger on Event to clear out the id from the object so as to null out the hyperlink field

Comment: also, ... you can have only one lookup from event to contact